# How to get the Windows client user ASPX C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have viewed and tried dozens of "answers" on StackOverflow, but none work.
I have a pretty simple aspx page with C# code behind.
The web site is on a Windows 2008R2 server.
The web site looks like (actual names changed):

```
MyServer - set for Anonymous Authentication  
 Application Pools
      ASP.NET v4.0 Classic - .Net 4.0, Classic pipeline, App Pool Identity
      MySiteAppPool - .Net 2.0, Integrated, runs under a Domain-wide Service identity (call it "mycompany\domservice")
   Sites
      MyMainSite - Windows Authentication, uses "MySiteAppPool"
         "AutoPrint" - my web app, Windows Authentication, uses "ASP.Net v4.0 Classic" app pool, ASP.NET Impersonation enabled
```

My "AutoPrint" web app has a start page "AutoPrint.aspx" and code behind ("AutoPrint.aspx.cs", plus several classes).

The server and main site are not alterable, as there are several other applications under this site.

The user currently invokes this app with :

```
http://MyServer/AutoPrint

Everything I have tried is returning the "mycompany\domservice" result:
Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString() - returns "mycompany\domservice"
System.Environment.UserName.ToString() - returns "domservice"
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString() - returns "mycompany\domservice"
```

What am I missing here?  Why is this so hard?

Further clarifications:
"mycompany\domservice" - the "domservice" account is just an ActiveDirectory account in the "mycompany" domain that has permissions to read/write directories needed by the site and other applications.  When installing the Site and additional web apps, we use that account as the "connect as" user.

What I am trying to do is to get the ActiveDirectory name of the Windows user account of the person who opened their browser and accessed this app.  If user "JJONES" logs into Windows and launches the app with "http://myserver/autoprint", I want to get either "JJONES" or "mycompany\JJONES" as the user name.

Comment: Set your website to use Windows Authentication in IIS, if you want to get the client user Identity info

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User gives IPrincipal of logon user

Comment: Both the main web site and my web app are set with Windows Authentication, as noted in the OP.

Comment: Just tested System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() - returned the same "mycompany\domservice" result.

Comment: What is `domservice`? Is it the impersonated username?

Comment: "domservice" is the domain-level account under which the web app (and various other "service" applications) runs in order to get directory access to the files under the site - the "Physical Path Credentials".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the helpful comments/suggestions.

The problem turned out to be a combination of factors.  The App Pool I was using was using App Pool Identity (which has limited rights), so I had to use a specific account (the domain service account) in the "Connect as..." for the physical path credentials in order to access certain files.

Changing to use an App Pool that used an account with sufficient privileges (the domain service account) allowed me to leave the "Connect as..." using Pass-through authentication when converting to application.

Voila - I now get the user credentials using pretty much any of the proposed methods.  After way too many hours of beating my head against the keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

If you use anonymous authentication, then the browser does not send any credentials (user id/password) to the server. Therefore if you want the client user id on the server, you have to use non-anonymous authentication, e.g,. Windows or Forms. You can use non-anonymous authentication and then allow or deny access to your web site to specific users or groups of users, or all users.

Comment: The web site and my web app both use "Windows Authentication".  The IIS Server itself is set for Anonymous authentication.  I do not control the server or IIS settings.  Surely there is some way to capture the user's Windows AD user name from the webpage and pass it to the backend?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at using HttpContext.User property ? This will give the current logged on user. After which point you may need to perform some nifty LDAP queries to get the username from AD. 
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx

You may want to see the below link on how to search AD on the link "[How can I search Active Directory by username using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865154/how-can-i-search-active-directory-by-username-using-c)"

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried that - noted in the comments on the OP.  "Just tested System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() - returned the same "mycompany\domservice" result. – Kim Crosser yesterday".   BTW - I didn't downvote you.

Comment: How odd. This should have worked. I am not worried about the down vote. I will be happy if it works for you and anyone else that is banging their heads against this particular problem. :-)