# C# Active Directory Search

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I have this powershell function and i want to make it as a C# function.
How can i put it into C#?

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {Name -Like 'myComp'} -property * | select DistinguishedName
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, happy to have you here. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, instead please [edit] your question with what you have already tried. If you have no clue I recommend the [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/07/04/querying-active-directory/) and looking the documentation of the [DirectoryEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry?view=netframework-4.8) class of C#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I search Active Directory by username using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865154/how-can-i-search-active-directory-by-username-using-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this quite easily. Add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and then use this code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 'YourDomain'))
{
    ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity (ctx, "name");

    if (computer != null)
    {
        // do whatever you need to do with your computer principal
        string distinguishedName = computer.DistinguishedName;
    }

}
```

**Update**: if you **don't know** your domain ........ - you can also use:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
```

in which case the principal context is created for the current domain you're located in.

Comment: i don't know my domain name. The Powershell code doesn't do this, simply filters all computernames and selects the required one, without domain name, server name etc.

Comment: `string domainName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN");`

Comment: thank you! this did the trick. Do you know if the domain name, that i don't know, is created from DC1.DC2.DC3.DC4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# in the following manner

1. Connect to the Domain controller and get the DomainContext
2. Use that to look up the computer objects based on a name.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName) 
{
    using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(ctx) { Name = "ServerName"}))
    {
        return srch.FindAll().Cast<ComputerPrincipal>().ToList().Select(x => x.DistinguishedName);
    }
}
```

Above returns a list of DistinguishedNames that matches the Server Name.

Comment: have no domain controler

Comment: You can use Environment.UserDomainName to get the current domain and use that to look up the computer.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers suggest using the [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement) namespace. While that will work, it is really just a wrapper around the [`System.DirectoryServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices) namespace to make things a bit easier to use. It does make things easier (sometimes) but it does so at the cost of performance.

For example, in all the examples you've been given, your code will retrieve *every attribute with a value* from the computer object in AD, even though you only want one attribute.

If you use [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher), you can make the search and retrieve only that one attribute that you want:

```cs
public string GetComputerDn(string computerName) {
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher {
        Filter = $"(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName={computerName}$))",
        PropertiesToLoad = { "distinguishedName" } //return only the distinguishedName attribute
    };
    var result = searcher.FindOne();
    if (result == null) return null;
    return (string) result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
}
```

Note that in AD, the `sAMAccountName` of computer objects is what you would normally refer to as the "computer name", followed by `$`, which is why the filter is what it is.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

Add reference to Active Directory Services (%programfiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\\System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll)

```
public string GetComputerName(string computerName)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "your domain name goes here"))
    {
        using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Active Directory Group Name goes here"))
        {
            var computers = @group.GetMembers(true);
            return computers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == computerName).DistinguishedName;
        }
    }

    return null; // or return "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to fetch a **computer** object - not a group ....

Comment: This is another way of retrieving it. I tried and its working in my case.

Comment: `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity` will not find a computer.